# Robots and containers minimization problem, approach needed

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

Given this [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/two-robots/problem):

> You have a warehouse with M containers filled with an infinite number
>   of candies. The containers are arranged in a single row, equally
>   spaced to be 1 meter apart. You also have 2 robots that can pick up 
>   1 piece of candy and transport it between any two containers.
>
> The robots take instructions in the form of queries consisting of two
>   integers, Ma and Mb, respectively. To execute a query, a robot travels to
>   container Ma, picks up 1 candy, transports it to container Mb, and then
>   stops at Mb until it receives another query.
>
> Calculate the minimum total distance the robots must travel to execute
>   N queries in order.
>
> Note: You choose which robot executes each query.

Initially I assumed that I should simply choose the robot which is closer to carry out the move, but this approach fails in some test cases, could anyone explain why this approach is not valid for all cases, and what is the right approach, Thanks.

Sample input and expected output [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ANJ88DVV74A8MHJ7k_BPcewUvPXd_abAf0rtftljVoQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the Dynamic programming category, and you yourself tagged your question `greedy` (your approach is indeed greedy). There will be cases when the minimum distance for a given query (local minimum) is not optimal for the full set of queries (global minimum). Hence you need to consider all possible assignments of robots to queries, but with DP techniques this is not an exhaustive search.

I don't want to detail the exact solution for you, since there are plenty of resources online on DP (make a 2-dimensional table of costs, moving across columns = robot 1, moving across rows = robot 2, find optimal path through the table, …). But I want to show you an example situation where the greedy approach is sub-optimal.

- `A` robot 1
- `B` robot 2
- `F` start point of query
- `T` end point of query

Solved with the greedy approach:

```
 (A)                  B
1 . . F . T . . . . . . // A is closer to F, travels 2 (to F) + 2 (to T) = 4
         (A)          B
2 . . . . . . F . T . . // A is closer to F, travels 2 (to F) + 2 (to T) = 4
                 (A)  B
3 F T . . . . . . . . . // A is closer to F, travels 8 (to F) + 1 (to T) = 9
    A                 B
```

Total distance traveled: `4 + 4 + 9 = 17`.

An optimal approach (there may be multiple):

```
 (A)                  B
1 . . F . T . . . . . . // A takes query, travels 2 (to F) + 2 (to T) = 4
          A          (B)
2 . . . . . . F . T . . // B takes query, travels 4 (to F) + 2 (to T) = 6
         (A)      B
3 F T . . . . . . . . . // A takes query, travels 4 (to F) + 1 (to T) = 5
    A             B
```

Total distance traveled: `4 + 6 + 5 = 15`.

Note that `B` took the second query even though it was not the closest to the start point.

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit and for the clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Working Code using dynamic programming  (as explained by Aurel Bílý) in C++:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector <pair <int,int > > input;
int dp[1002][1002];
int m,n;
int dis(int a,int b)
{
    if(a == 0) return abs(input[b-1].first-input[b-1].second);
    return abs(input[a-1].second-input[b-1].first)+abs(input[b-1].first-input[b-1].second);
}
int func(int i,int j)
{
    if(i+1 == n+1 || j+1 == n+1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    //cout<<i<<" "<<j<<endl;
    if(dp[i][j] != -1)
     return dp[i][j];
    int result = INT_MAX;
    result = min(func(i,j+1)+dis(j,j+1),func(j,j+1)+dis(i,j+1));
    return dp[i][j] = result; 
}
int main()
{
    int t;cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>m>>n;
        input.clear();
        input.resize(n);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            int a,b;
            cin>>a>>b;
            input[i] = make_pair(a,b);
        }
        memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
        int first = abs(input[0].first-input[0].second);
       // int second = abs(input[1].first-input[1].second);
        int val = func(0,1)+first;
        cout<<val<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```